# Transferring a JS Array to Python using AJAX & Flask - not working

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask

I am experiencing some problems with my code. My data loader to python isn't working. Here is my HTML site (using Jinja syntax from a base.html):

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block head %}
<title>PPO Count</title>
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <!-- Header -->
    <div class="header">
        <h2 class='title'>Prototype 1: Pet Owner Viz</h2>
    </div>
    <!-- Button Panel-->

    <!-- Vis Box -->
    <div class='canvas'>
        <div class="container">
            <div class='button-box'>
                <button id='Bx' type="button" onclick='toggleClickedBuz("Bx", "Bx")'>Bx</button>
                <button id='By' type="button" onclick='toggleClickedBuz("By", "By")'>By</button>
                <button id='Bz' type="button" onclick='toggleClickedBuz("Bz", "Bz")'>Bz</button>
                <button id='loadData'>Load Data</button>
            </div>
            <div class='viz-box'>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/main.js"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

Notice the buttons? What occurs is that onclick, it goes into an array using JS. In sum this function deletes duplicate entries and changes the colour of the buttons on screen to highlight their selection.

```
const vizBox = d3.select('.viz-box');
const svg = vizBox.append('svg');


// Create button click array

var clickedBusinesses = [];

function toggle(business) {
    clickedBusinesses[business] = !clickedBusinesses[business];
  };

function getClickedBusinesses() {
return Object.keys(clickedBusinesses).filter(key => clickedBusinesses[key]);
};


// Update array and change button colour to reflect selection
function toggleClickedBuz( bizStr , id ) {
    if(clickedBusinesses.includes(bizStr)){
       // removing duplicate element from that array, dependant on button pressed
       clickedBusinesses = clickedBusinesses.filter( cb => cb !== bizStr );
       document.getElementById( id ).style.backgroundColor='white';
    }else{
        // else push it to the array
       clickedBusinesses.push(bizStr)
       document.getElementById( id ).style.backgroundColor='red';
    }
    var json_string = JSON.stringify(clickedBusinesses)
    console.log(json_string)
};

window.onload = function() {
    d3.select('loadData').onclick = function() {
        doWork()
    };
}

function doWork() {
    $.post('receiver', json_string, function() {

    });
event.preventDefault();
}
```

button id='loadData' isn't working, I can't get my jsonified JS array into python. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`d3.select` does not return a native DOM node, it returns a so called `d3-selection` that doesn't know anything about `onclick`. Instead, you should use the `.on` method of a `d3-selection` to register event listeners as described here: https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#handling-events

Alternatives:

Instead of using `d3` to select elements, use the native `.querySelector` method: `document.querySelector('#loadData').onclick = ...`.

Or use `jQuery` for it: `$('#loadData').on('click', ...)`.

Comment: Thanks David. 

Getting this now: status Code: 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR

Comment: It seems there's something wrong with your Python code, too. Please open a new question.